# true false quiz in c#

Tags: c#

I'm building a auto guiz generator in C# in which take the pdf file from user and generate MCQS Fill in the blanks and true false. I completed the two modules MCQS and Fill in the blanks but have the problem in generating true-false values in a random way.

So my problem is: how can i randomly generate true and false values?

Comment: I don't think it's that ambiguous.  He just has issues with the English language.  I think he's asking how he can generate a random subset of true/false questions from a larger set.

Comment: @Josh +1. resistance is futile, the stack overflow police has already struck again :-(

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question. It may be phrased by a non-native English speaker, but it is to the point, complete, not ambiguous and can certainly be answered in a reasonable way.

Comment: Seems like a few people care more about badges than helping others out.

Comment: as josh said i want to make a sentences which will be true or not .for example Asia is the biggest continent on earth. that sentence is true but how can i make it false??

Comment: thanks for editing jeroenh because i'm not good in english..

Answer (score 8):

```
public bool GetRandomBoolean(Random rnd)
{
    return rnd.Next(0, 2) == 0;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.next

**Edit**: Note that you should not use this method in this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    bool randomBool = GetRandomBoolean(new Random());
}
```

That would generate always the same "random" boolean since it's *[seeded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx)* with the same time. Instead you should reuse the random instance, f.e. in this way:

```
var rnd = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    bool randomBool = GetRandomBoolean(rnd);
}
```

Comment: as josh said i want to make a sentences which will be true or not .for example Asia is the biggest continent on earth. that sentence is true but how can i make it false??

Comment: @ABDULMANAN: I'm afraid that i've not understood the requirement fully. What should be the desired result? Do you want the sentence _"Asia is the smallest continent on earth"_ or _"Asia is not the biggest continent on earth"_ so that it can be answered correctly with `false` or simply a random boolean as my answer shows?

Comment: Maybe it's because i don't know what a _MCQS_ is, but it's difficult to understand what you are doing (without code) and what does not work. So you want just to insert a _"not"_ at a predefined place in a string when a random boolean was `false`??

Comment: multiple choice questions(MCQS).so you are saying i add randomly "not" in my sentence which is predefined ??

Comment: @ABDULMANAN: If I were you, i  would edit this question(or let it die and create a new one) and provide more informations. What have you tried(code), provide one or two sample questions and the desired result. Note that you (meanwhile) know how to create a random boolean to avoid misunderstandings.